# IDEA freezes when I execute Gradle tests in debug mode

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I want to execute tests in my Gradle project in debug mode. So I've added a configuration in IDEA for executing Gradle tasks "debug".

But when I run it in Debug mode I see the following output from IDEA:

```
:prepareInplaceWebAppFolder UP-TO-DATE
:createInplaceWebAppFolder UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:prepareInplaceWebAppClasses UP-TO-DATE
:prepareInplaceWebApp UP-TO-DATE
:appRunDebug
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
<It freezes here>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, you've executed a gradle task separate from Idea's debugger and it's waiting for some debugger to be connected. That means, you have not properly configured a debug configuration in your IDE.

As for Idea, you may take a look at their [create debug configuration for Gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/create-run-debug-configuration-for-gradle-tasks.html) section of documentation. You can simply create a debug configuration in one click from Gradle menu in Idea version 14.+ and don't need to set additional flag for Gradle to start it in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle JVM is waiting for you to connect a debugger on port 5005